# How to read and write animated GIF with transparency

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here's a (theoretically) simple task I have at hand:

1. Load **transparent** animated GIF from disk (or buffer)
2. Convert all individual frames into NumPy arrays. Each frame **WITH ALPHA CHANNEL**
3. Save NumPy arrays back into **transparent** animated GIF

Output file size is irrelevant, all I really need is to have are two identical GIFs - the original input image and the one saved in step 3.

What does matter to me though it de/encoding speed so pure Python solutions (without C bindings to the underlying imaging library) are not considered.

Attached (at the very bottom), you will find an example GIF I am using for testing.

I tried pretty much every single approach that comes to mind. Either the resulting GIF (step 3) is terribly butchered, rendered in grayscale only, or (at best), looses transparency and is saved on either white or black background.

Here's what I tried:

**Read with Pillow:**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("animation.gif")

npArray = []

for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    npArray.append(np.array(frame))

return npArray
```

**Read with imageio:**

```
import imageio

npArr = []

im = imageio.get_reader("animation.gif")

for frame in im:
    npArr.append(np.array(frame))

return npArr
```

**Read with MoviePy:**

```
from moviepy.editor import *

npArr = []

clip = VideoFileClip("animation.gif")

for frame in clip.iter_frames():
    npArr.append(np.array(frame))

return npArr
```

**Read with PyVips:**

```
vi = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("animation.gif", n=-1)

pageHeight = vi.get("page-height")
frameCount = int(vi.height / pageHeight)

npArr = []

for i in range(0, frameCount):
    vi = vi.crop(0, i * pageHeight + 0, vi.width, pageHeight).write_to_memory()

    frame = np.ndarray(
            buffer = vi,
            dtype = np.uint8,
            shape = [pageHeight, vi.width, 3]
    )

    npArr.append(frame)

return npArr
```

**Save with Pillow:**

```
images = []

for frame in frames:
    im = Image.fromarray(frame)
    images.append(im)

images[0].save(
    "output.gif",
    format = "GIF",
    save_all = True,
    loop = 0,
    append_images = images,
    duration = 40,
    disposal = 3
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're encountering an issue because you're not saving the palette associated with each frame. When you convert each frame to an array, the resulting array doesn't contain any of the palette data which specifies what colours are included in the frame. So, when you construct a new image from each frame, the palette is not present, and Pillow doesn't know what colour palette it should use for the frame.

Also, when saving the GIF, you need to specify the colour to use for transparency, which we can just extract from the original image.

Here's some code which (hopefully) produces the result you want:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("ex.gif")

frames = []
# Each frame can have its own palette in a GIF, so we need to store
# them individually
fpalettes = []
transparency = im.info['transparency']

for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    frames.append(np.array(frame))
    fpalettes.append(frame.getpalette())

# ... Do something with the frames

images = []

for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
    im = Image.fromarray(frame)
    im.putpalette(fpalettes[i])
    images.append(im)

images[0].save(
        "output.gif",
        format="GIF",
        save_all=True,
        loop=0,
        append_images=images,
        duration=40,
        disposal=2,
        transparency=transparency
)
```